# Problemas para com a consulta no banco de dados (Sistema de pesquisa)

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando criar um sistema de pesquisa no db no entanto esta retornando apenas um resultado, o último endereço na tabela (Eu havia conseguido fazer com que retornassem todos, no entanto depois alterando o layout eu fui testar e não deu mais, mesmo apagando tudo e retornando de quando funcionou).

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="db";
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);

$verifica = 0;
$city = $_POST['city'];
$bairrop = $_POST['bairrop'];

if(!empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['bairrop'])){
$result_search = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE cidade LIKE '%$city%' AND bairro LIKE '%$bairrop%'";
$resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
$verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
}elseif (!empty($_POST['city'])) {
$result_search = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE cidade LIKE '%$city%'";
$resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
$verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
}elseif (!empty($_POST['bairrop'])) {
$result_search = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE bairro LIKE '%$bairrop%'";
$resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
$verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
}


if($verifica > 0){
  while($row_search = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_search)) {
  $nome = $row_search['nome_usuario'];
}
}else{
  echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado.";
}
?>
```

2:
Estou usando o bootstrap e gostaria que eles retornassem da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="media">
<div class="media-left">
<a href="#">
  <img class="media-object" src="AVATAR" alt="...">
</a>
</div>
<div class="media-body">
<h4 class="media-heading">AQUI O NOME</h4>
DESCRIÇÃO
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função mysql_fetch_array() retorna o valor aonde o ponteiro se encontra e, após retornar o valor, move o ponteiro uma posição para a frente.

Imagine uma tabela cuja coluna é denominada de "nome_usuario" e a seta (->) é o ponteiro da lista.

```
-> Beltrano Tal
   Ciclano Soares
   Fulano Silva
```

Quando utilizamos a função mysql_fetch_array(), ele retorna a primeira linha:

```
   while($row_search = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_search)) {
   $nome = $row_search['nome_usuario'];
```

Neste momento a variável **$nome** assume o valor **Beltrano Tal** e o ponteiro move-se uma posição para frente, e nossa lista fica da seguinte maneira:

```
   Beltrano Tal
-> Ciclano Soares
   Fulano Silva
```

Neste momento a variável **$nome** assume o valor **Ciclano Soares** e o ponteiro move-se uma posição para frente, e assim sucessivamente.

> Então é por isso que no seu while na variável `$nome` só aparece o último nome.

Ao executar o `while` o valor da variável `$nome` está sendo sobrescrito porque você não está concatenando os valores.

Você pode por exemplo fazer assim para concatenar

`$nome .= $row_search['nome_usuario'];`

ou

```
$nome = $nome.$row_search['nome_usuario'];
```

É claro que do jeito que está acima os nomes retornarão todos juntos. Cabe a você decidir a forma que a variável `$nome` deve ser construída para posterior apresentação. Por exemplo:

```
`$nome .= "<li>" . $row_search['nome_usuario'] . "</li>";`
```

e no lugar que deva ser apresentado por exemplo:

```
echo "<ul>".$nome."</ul>";
```